# Email to Case in Lightning Experience

Tags: email2case, lightning

wrt winter 16 [release note](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_e2c.htm) Email to Case feature available only in Salesforce Classic edition only, *so this means if we enable Lightning where email to case already deployed – what is the problem will be faced?* or we cannot even enable Lightning if we already enabled the Email 2 Case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my experiments on this topic. I started with winter 16 updated developer org which is in SFDC classic - created email to case on demand routing address and as expected it worked perfectly. (it is just prerequisite of my analysis).

Then I enabled Lightning Experience, and even switched my user account to Lightning. Then I tried creating another email to case routing address and tested - it works perfectly in lightning experience too.

However - I really couldn't understand what this winter 16 [release notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_e2c.htm) document referring to.